# Describing the following region in the complex plane $|z-1|<\Im(z)$

Tags: complex-numbers, solution-verification

I was considering the region shown in the title

$$|z-1|<\Im(z)$$

I took the approach of considering $z\in \mathbb{C}$ and taking $z=x+iy$ then breaking down the inequality as follows

$$|z-1|=\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}<y$$

squaring both sides

$$(x-1)^2+y^2<y^2$$

but this gives $(x-1)^2<0$ which is impossible therefore I said that the set of points satisfying the inequality would be empty, but my professor keeps telling me that the solution is wrong am I missing something

Comment: You are right and your professor is wrong. More simply $|\Im z| =|\Im (z-1)| \leq |z-1| <\Im z$ is impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we consider $|z - 1| \le r$ in the complex plane. Then let $z = a + bi$ and so we have $\sqrt{(a - 1)^2 + b^2} \le r$ or $(a - 1)^2 + b^2 \le r^2$. This is the set of points that have a circle with center $(a + 1, b)$ and radius $r$ as the boundary. In other words, you may think of it as concentric circles with that center and radii from $0$ to $r$, inclusive. If we change the inequality to being strict, then it the set of concentric circles with radii $0$ to $r$ without including $r$.

Clearly, this is perfectly fine for $r > 0$, but if $r < 0$, then this does not make sense. So consider $\text{Im}(z) > 0$, since we may exclude the other case entirely. If $\text{Im}(z) > 0$, then we proceed with your steps and find that $(a - 1)^2 + b^2 < b^2$, which indeed also has no solutions.

There was mistake when you squared both sides of the inequality since you assumed that $y > 0$.

Since neither $\text{Im}(z) > 0$ or $< 0$ has solutions, we can conclude there are no solutions at all. (note $b = 0$ immediately gives $(a - 1)^2 < 0 $)

Comment: “ There was mistake when you squared both sides of the inequality since you assumed that y>0”: y MUST be positive (strictly, I may add) because it is STRICTLY greater than a positive (or nonnegative)quantity (a square root).

Comment: @insipidintegrator We are starting from an arbitrary complex number. That complex number is not guaranteed to have a nonnegative imaginary part. What you said is true in the sense that is how we arrive at a contradiction.

Comment: Ffim the question statement itself the one can conclude y>0.

Comment: To be honest I'm not quite sure what you are arguing here. I excluded $y < 0$ at the very start: "Clearly, this is perfectly fine for >0, but if <0, then this does not make sense."

We started with a statement, and we showed the statement is bogus by considering all possible $y$ in different intervals.

Comment: Meaning that it is a mistake of rigor (not showing why $\Im(z)$) cant be less than zero ?
@politeproofs

Comment: @Eulerroid I'm not sure. I can't say for certain, but in your solution, you did assume that $y > 0$. Now, of course this has to be the case, but I think for such a problem I think part of the solution is explicitly excluding a case like that.